# What did Ken Thompson mean when he said, "I'd spell creat with an 'e'."?

Tags: history

> [Ken Thompson, the creator of Unix, was once asked what he'd do if he had 
>   it to do over again. He said, "I'd spell creat with an 'e'."](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Kenneth_Thompson)

What is Ken referring to? Is there a "creat" command?

Comment: Actually, he most likely didn't mean what he said: he probably meant that he'd spell `creat` with *two* 'e's - after all, one is already present. Of course, the implicit message being that UNIX turned out the way it was meant to be without any substantial changes only requiring fixing this [one] typo.

Answer (score 58):

It's a Unix system call that creates a file:  At a Unix shell prompt, type `man 2 creat` to learn more.

Man pages are also available online these days:

- [Linux's `creat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/creat.2.html)
- [POSIX generic man-page for the function/syscall: `creat(3p)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/creat.3p.html).

Comment: BTW, he finally did it: https://github.com/golang/go/commit/c90d392ce3d3203e0c32b3f98d1e68c4c2b4c49b

Answer (score 37):

Not only he refers to `man 2 creat` system call.  He also refers to the obsolete trends to save on every tiny character, where possible, sometimes this being only confusing, especially now, when typing and storing another character is rarely an obstacle.

Comment: I think in the context of the question he was only referring to creat(). The point he was making was there was nothing about Unix he would have done differently except for this small spelling error in the system call to create a file.

Comment: @jmucchiello, it's not a spelling error. It's a deliberate (albeit non-standard) abbreviation.  It fits with the heavy use of abbreviations like `fcntl`, `ls`, `mv`, etc, in general.

Comment: Agree, but I love those abbrvtns even when we have TBs to store :)

Comment: Teletype keys are hard to press. It was beneficial to save a few letters. First ones that could be eliminated were vowels and redundant consonants.

Comment: It's a false economy to use terse variable names, because we almost always read code more than we write it.

Comment: It's not false economy when Teletype keys are involved.

Answer (score 32):

I'm six years late to answer, but I believe that the extant answers all miss the point of Thompson's quote.

> I'd spell creat with an 'e'.

Ken Thompson is not lamenting the name of the function used to open and possibly create a file. **Rather, he is expressing that Unix was done properly, i.e. there is nothing *major* that should have been done differently.**

The **subtle** point is that Unix architecture is sound, and the implementations are fine. One would need to [bikeshed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality) to find anything to improve in Unix. Thus, the obvious nitpick about the name of a common system call.

Comment: Right, he wants to tell us, that the UNIX architecture can be improved in very tiny aspects. But basically UNIX has done it right. BTW. `creat` is a system call not a CLI command.

Answer (score 25):

It refers to the UNIX system call to create new files. Linkers on some machines were limited to identifiers of at most 6 characters. Apparently, Ken had to work with such a linker and hence the *create* system call was shortened to *creat* to match this limitation. The irony is that *create* does too.

See also: [What does the 9th commandment mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682719/what-does-the-9th-commandment-mean)

Comment: The 6 character limit translated to 5, as the compiler (in order to avoid user symbols clashing with compiler generated ones) prepended a `'_'` before user variable/function names, and was careful not to use `'_'` when generating symbols.

Comment: @vonbrand: That doesn't seem to explain how `unlink` or `umount` could exist, however, which I would think are contemporary with `creat`.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Well, it's quite possible the linker had this limitation, while the compiler did not. So `umount` would clash with `umoun` or `umounx` or whatever, but the name would be allowed. But that's pure speculation :)